# JS doesn't fully appear in screen, but fully appear in console.log

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I write a javascript code to draw a table based on my JSON.
There is something weird tought. I write the code to draw a table that will appear in my screen, but it doesn't appear fully. But its appear fully if i declare it in `console.log`. Whats wrong now?

this is the screenshoot of the table and `console.log` : http://prntscr.com/g5shkn
*Sry it doesn't imgur.

Description :

1. Its the table that rendered from the json, as you can see it just have 3 `<tr></tr>`, the `user`,`produk A paket A`, and `produk B paket B`
2. Its the `console.log` version from the table, you can see their have 3 `<tr></tr>` but have `<td></td>` in them.

and if i check it with inspect from developer tools in my chrome , its doesn't there (this is the link to the screenshoot : http://prntscr.com/g5sp7q). If you see my code, there is something called `<tr class="trBot"></tr>`, but in the `inspect session` there is no `trBot` in that place.

in this is my javascript code :

```
    $.when(
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/598960ad410000d300820df5',
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax User berjalan, berikut adalah daftar Jumlah User dari Produk yang diterima : ");
                $.each(result, function (index, el) {
                    console.log("jumlah user : " + el.jumlah_user + " , id jumlah user : " + el.id);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                $('#prosesloaddata').hide();
                $('#dialogerror').show();
                $("#pesanerror1").html("Terjadi Masalah, Silahkan Periksa Kembali Koneksi Internet Anda.");
                $("#pesanerror2").html(xhr.error);
                $("#pesanerror3").html("");
                console.log("error ketika memanggil data JSON Jumlah User dengan AJAX,", xhr.error);
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5989607c410000d300820df4',
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax Paket berjalan, berikut adalah daftar nama Paket dari produk yang diterima : ");
                $.each(result, function (index, el) {
                    console.log("nama paket : " + el.nama + " , id nama paket : " + el.id);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                $('#prosesloaddata').hide();
                $('#dialogerror').show();
                $("#pesanerror1").html("Terjadi Masalah, Silahkan Periksa Kembali Koneksi Internet Anda.");
                $("#pesanerror2").html(xhr.error);
                $("#pesanerror3").html("");
                console.log("error ketika memanggil data JSON Paket Produk dengan AJAX,", xhr.error);
            }
        }),
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/598960cf410000d800820df7',
            dataType: "JSON",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(result){
                console.log("Ajax Harga berjalan, berikut adalah daftar harga dari produk yang diterima : ");
                $('#prosesloaddata').hide();
                $.each(result, function (index, el) {
                    $.each(el, function (index1, el1) {
                        console.log("harga paket : " + el1.harga + " , id harga paket : " + el1.id + " , tanggal efektif : " + el1.tanggal_efektif);
                    })
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
                $('#prosesloaddata').hide();
                $('#dialogerror').show();
                $("#pesanerror1").html("Terjadi Masalah, Silahkan Periksa Kembali Koneksi Internet Anda.");
                $("#pesanerror2").html(xhr.error);
                $("#pesanerror3").html("");
                console.log("error ketika memanggil data JSON Harga dengan AJAX,", xhr.error);
            }
        })
    ).then(function(a, b, c){
         class arranger {
             constructor(a, b, c) {
                 this.a = a;
                 this.b = b;
                 this.c = c;
                 this.p = "";
             }
             qq() {
                 var packer = [],
                     y;
                 c = c[0];
                 for (var x = 0; x < c.length; x++) {
                     var wd = typeof packer[[c[x]['nama_id']]];
                     if (wd == "undefined") {
                         packer[c[x]['nama_id']] = [{
                             "harga": c[x]['harga'],
                             "jumlah_user_id": c[x]['jumlah_user_id']
                         }];
                     } else {
                         packer[c[x]['nama_id']].push({
                             "harga": c[x]['harga'],
                             "jumlah_user_id": c[x]['jumlah_user_id']
                         });
                     }
                 }
                 var p = "<tr>";
                 for (x in a[0]) {
                     p += "<th>" + a[0][x]['jumlah_user'] + " user</th>";
                 }
                 p += "</tr>";
                 for (x in b[0]) {
                     p += '<tr class="trTop"><td colspan="' + (a[0].length - 2) + '">' + b[0][x]['nama'] + '<td colspan="2">' + b[0][x]['masa_training'] + ' ' + b[0][x]['masa_maintenance'] + '</td></tr>';
                     if (typeof packer[b[0][x]['id']] !== "undefined") {
                         p += '<tr class="trBot">';
                         for (y in packer[b[0][x]['id']]) {
                             p += '<td>' + packer[b[0][x]['id']][y]['harga'] + '</td>';
                         }
                         p += '</tr>';
                     }
                 }
                 return p;
             }
             iii($qwe) {
                 this.p = $qwe;
             }
             zzz() {
                 document.getElementById('wg').innerHTML = this.p;
             }
         }
         (function () {
            var $ar = new arranger(a, b, c);
            $ar.iii($ar.qq());
            console.log($ar.qq());
            $ar.zzz()
         })();
    });
```

P.S :

1. mocky.io isn't my real JSON API link, i just used it since my API still in localhost, but for sure, its contain the same JSON.
2. the `console.log` that mentioned in the screenshoot is come from `console.log($ar.qq());`

Sorry for my english and the language i used in my code, Just ask me anything if the information that i write here is doesn't enough for you. Thanks guys.

Edit : In case you need it, this my css code :

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    border-collapse:separete !important; 
}
td {
    padding:10px !important;
}
.trTop td:last-child {
    text-align:right !important;
}
.trBot td {
    text-align:right !important;
}
```

Edit 2 : i tried it manually (copy paste the html table line from the `console.log` manually to `<table id="wg"></table>` and this is the result : 
http://prntscr.com/g5ssd8  , and this is the html code :

```
        <table id="wg">
            <tr>
                <th>1 user</th>
                <th>2 user</th>
                <th>5 user</th>
                <th>30 user</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trTop">
                <td colspan="2">Produk A Paket A
                <td colspan="2">1 x 1 Jam 1 Bulan</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trBot">
                <td>1000</td>
                <td>2000</td>
                <td>3000</td>
                <td>4000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="trTop">
                <td colspan="2">Produk A Paket B
                <td colspan="2">1 x 2 Jam 1 Bulan</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two td closing tags missing:

- After "Produk A Paket A"
- After "Produk A Paket B"

Add `</td>` after them, whereever you create your html and the problem should be solved.

Comment: sry @kloker i already change it, add </td> after that, but its still doesn't work, have other idea?

Answer (score 0):

well, its solved now.

Thanks everyone.

I just add this :

```
this.p = p;
```

before this code run :

```
return p;
```